# How to google for developer info for Windows 8.1 store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have been developing a Windows 8.1 store app for a couple of months and have tried a number of different keywords to narrow down my searches for developer information.

Eg. If I'm looking for how to implement app settings, I might try, in google:

`metro app settings`

`winrt app settings` (best for SO and msdn.microsoft.com answers)

`store app settings`

`windows 8.1 store app settings` (sometimes finds blogs and tutorials missed by `winrrt`)

`xaml app settings`

When I find a code keyword related to the topic (eg. `ApplicationData`) then I can start narrowing it down. (eg. `windows 8.1 store app settings applicationdata`).

There are some problems with this:

1. Verbosity. One of best methods (`Windows 8.1 Store App`) is much longer than seems necessary for a developer search
2. The two best methods (`winrt` and `windows 8.1 store app`) can produce quite different results
3. `Windows 8.1` is generic. I am as likely to get user information, as developer information before hitting on the keywords
4. The best keywords for going straight to developer sites (and blogs) are "metro" and "winrt" and "xaml", but: "metro" is obsolete; "winrt" is often not included in a blog which has a good article on the particular topic (such blogs usually file under 'Windows 8.1 Store App'); "xaml" brings up silverlight and wpf solutions which aren't supported in store apps
5. If I use `Windows 8.1` I may miss useful info written for `Windows 8`, but if I use `Windows 8` I might get obsolete info.

Now that I've typed all that, I think I've got my answer: Use `Winrt 8.1`.

Comment: With another 6 months experience of developing store apps, I've found that most interesting issues in XAML and data binding are common with WPF and silverlight, so, if its just a XAML question then it's best to search for `XAML ...`, or `WPF ...`. This sometimes brings up code which doesn't work in WinRT, but these false positives are worth the extra scope I get when I omit`winrt` from the search terms.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I use when searching for APIs is something like

`windows ui bitmapimage`

or

`windows xaml path`

As for more specific problems - there are usually things I can put in quotes that I want to find exact phrases for like

`"error 0x80000004"`

Comment: Thanks, but once I know a keyword I'm OK (see `applicationdata` in my questions). In WinRT I'm still finding my way round, and don't know what keywords I'm looking for. For the moment, I'll stick with `winrt 8.1`